# PDFKit::NoExecutableError in EmployeesController#to_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I was using PdfKit for generating pdf from my Html template till now.
But suddenly it has started giving Error

The error message is given below

```
No wkhtmltopdf executable found at /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf >> Please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF
```

I have used

```
html = render_to_string(:action => "Pdf_template/Pdf.html.erb", :layout => false)

kit = PDFKit.new(html)
```

for generating PDF

I have tried to resolve it by installing gem wkhtmltopdf
but it didn't helped
the problem is wkhtmltopdf executable is present in my production and and my local environment but this error is occuring only in production not in my local environment

Thank you in advance

Comment: did you add initializer file pdfkit.rb with this content `PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'PATH/TO/wkhtmltopdf'
end`

Comment: please try to run `which wkhtmltopdf` command , so you will get the version of wkhtmltopdf, if its currently installed or not

Comment: Thanks for replying and yes, this code is written in pdfkit.rb file

moreover, I checked the version using  which wkhtmltopdf 
it is the same version written in pdfkit.rb

Comment: ur project is on heroku ? it is possible that the path `'PATH/TO/wkhtmltopdf'` is not same on production

Comment: `gem wkhtmltopdf` is there on production ?

Comment: my project is on rails
and i tried once by installing `gem wkhtmltopdf `
but it did not solved the problem so i removed it

Comment: But `gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"` is present

Comment: can you add both gem and check whether its working or not ?

Comment: Plz also add wkhtmltopdf on your machine `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: it must be issue of config. and 90% path is not correct on productin

Comment: `sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf` added but issue not solved

Comment: `gem wkhtmltopdf` also added still same error

Comment: Sorry @Vishal you were right,
path was incorrect 
I was checking path at the wrong place.

Anyways , Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Should i post answer of it ? will you upvote and accept it ? because it will help other user to resolve problem in future

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: its been 10 days :D

Comment: added my answer , please accept and upvote it :)

Comment: thanks anjali, let me know if you want help in future :)

Comment: I just asked a question if you want to help

Comment: answered for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please cross verify the install path for wkhtmltopdf, i am pretty confident its issue of path, below is the script where you have to add correct path of wkhtmltopdf

**config/initializers/wkhtmltopdf.rb**

```
PDFKit.configure do |config| 
  config.wkhtmltopdf = 'PATH/TO/wkhtmltopdf' 
end
```